# If I uninstall mysql with brew, does it drop the databases too?

Tags: terminal, macos, mysql

I want to cleanup my system and uninstall mysql. If I do so with:

```
brew uninstall mysql
```

will the databases also been deleted? I don't want to leave them on the harddisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [Default-Database-Location](https://serverfault.com/a/698257/459065) Thanks Tom. I didn't changed it after installing mysql with brew.

So after `brew uninstall mysql` I had to remove the following folder:

**mysql** inside of **/usr/local/var/**

I also searched for the files from [this checklist](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d), but found nothing so only did the last thing: `brew cleanup` and was done.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the location of the database file on disk.

Upon uninstalling **mysql**, the mysql installation directory is deleted, which is `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql` in the default install.